# can not take values in mysql database from the android app ,when it goes in background class , the app stop working

Tags: java, android, mysql

after entering the values when i click on register button and it goes in the background class my app stop working , here is the code of that method

```
     public void userReg(View view)
     {
      name = ET_NAME.getText().toString();
    user_name = ET_USER_NAME.getText().toString();
    user_pass =ET_USER_PASS.getText().toString();
    String method = "register";
    BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(this);
    backgroundTask.execute(method,name,user_name,user_pass);
    finish(); }
```

here is the code of where actual working will perform in backgroundtask class

```
      protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
      String reg_url = "http://10.0.2.2/webapp/register.php";
    String login_url = "http://10.0.2.2/webapp/login.php";
    String method = params[0];
    if (method.equals("register")) {
        String name = params[1];
        String user_name = params[2];
        String user_pass = params[3];
        try {
            URL url = new URL(reg_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            //httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream OS = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS, "UTF-8"));
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("user", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("user_name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user_name, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("user_pass", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user_pass, "UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            OS.close();
            InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            IS.close();
            //httpURLConnection.connect();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return "Registration Success...";
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

here is the onpostExecute method , the problem is result receives null value form the background thats why its gonna crash and i dnt know how to fix it

```
       protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
   if (result.equals("Registration Success...")) {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {

       // Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

i dont know whats wrong in this code, as i am new related to server side i took help from youtube video in making this code here is the logcat output

```
   Process: com.awan.app.webappdb, PID: 26144
   java.lang.NullPointerException
        at       com.awan.app.webappdb.BackgroundTask.onPostExecute(BackgroundTask.java:84)
        at com.awan.app.webappdb.BackgroundTask.onPostExecute(BackgroundTask.java:25)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Calling finish() will end your Activity (and associated tasks) - if you want something to run in the background when your App is not active, you should look into creating a Service.

Comment: @adelphus so what you recommended me,? after commenting a finish() , still am getting app stop working ,

Comment: Take a look at (or post) your logcat output - it will show you the source file and line number that is causing your App to crash.

Comment: @adelphus ok , am posting the log cat output

Comment: @ArslanAliAwan the stacktrace you posted is pointing to: " com.awan.app.webappdb.BackgroundTask.onPostExecute(BackgroundTask.java:84)" the problem is there in `onPostExecute` but you haven't published the relevant code so we can't help you further.

Comment: @alfasin i did post my onPostExecute method , so please check it and help me

Comment: @alfasin the problem is it receives null value from the background thats y it gonna crash , help me

Answer (score 0):

Since you allow `doInBackground` to return null you should be checking for null values in `onPostExecute`.

A quick way to change the code so that it can handle null value is to flip the order of the operators inside the if-condition:

```
if("Registration success...".equals(result)) { ...
```

Comment: i did handle the null value but still i cant understand why am getting the null values from doinBackground Method,

Comment: @ArslanAliAwan your comment is unclear. See the last line of the method - you explicitly `return null;`

Comment: as i mentioned i took help from youtube in making this code but if i comment this return null statment it shows error "Missing return statement " in this method i have to use  this return null statement and it will run if  if (method.equals("register")) is becomes false i think soo

Comment: @ArslanAliAwan please read my answer again. Further, if you should *never* return null from this method - you should throw an exception in case the `if` condition failed: `if (method.equals("register"))`

Comment: yes i did flip the orders of operators, now application will run properly but my database is still empty it does not put values(do in background method) in my database , can you give me ur email id or something , so i can clearly talk to you on this issue , it will be more good for me

Comment: The fact that the DB remains empty could be due to many things: does the code in doInBackground() gets inside the "if"? does your PHP script receive the request? add log prints to the PHP script on different steps to make sure that all the parameters are passed properly, and see that the INSERT request doesn't fail. Good luck!

Comment: Thnks alot for your help it will be helpful for me THnks again